# File ended while scanning use of \frame

Tags: beamer, errors

Please help me out:

```
\documentclass[presentation,pdftex]{beamer}%handout                 %**DONT CHANGE
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{movie15}
\usetheme{Madrid} %Warsaw Berlin Bergen Berkeley Boadilla Madrid AnnArbor
%\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{green!5}{red!10}
%\beamertemplategridbackground[3mm]
%\structuresmallcapsserif
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}               %**DONT CHANGE
%\useoutertheme{infolines}                  
\usepackage[english]{babel}                         %**DONT CHANGE
\logo{\includegraphics[width=8mm]{gsmonoN}} %**DONT CHANGE
\usepackage{graphicx} %**DONT CHANGE
%\usepackage{epstopdf} %**DONT CHANGE}
\begin{document}    %**DONT CHANGE
\title[\color{white}]{High Density data transfer through optical Free-Space communication}
%\includegraphics[width=12mm]{gsmonoN.png}
\author[Vanya Mishra]
{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width = 20mm]{gsmonoN}\\   %**DONT CHANGE
    Major Project Phase-1 Presentation by\\
{\bf Vanya Mishra}\\
    (M.Tech., Optoelectronics) \\ 
    \vskip 2mm 
    Guided by\\
    {\color{blue} Dr. J. T. Andrews}\\
    Professor\\
    Department of Applied Physics,   \\ %**DONT CHANGE
    Shri G S Institute of Technology \& Science Indore\\ %**DONT CHANGE
    \vskip 1mm 
    %Venue\\ 
%{\color{red}   Appl. Photonics Laboratory, Dept. Appl. Physics}
    \vskip 2mm 
%\color{blue} Name of the Event Here\\
    {\color{blue} December 20,   2016}
    \end{center}}
\date[{\textcolor{yellow}{\textbf{Dec. 20,   2016}}}]{} 
\vskip 5mm
\institute[SGSITS,   Indore]{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get errors about the missing graphics file, but after adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphics}` at the beginning, the file compiles without errors (`pdflatex`).

Comment: For us, who haven't your "gsmonoN"` picure, you should add option `demo` to `\documentclass[...]{beamer}. Also loading `graphicx` package is not necessary since it already leaded by `beamer`. I also take a liberty and add missing `\end{document}` to your MWE. As noted Heiko Oberdiek in his comment, the this changes your MWE compiles without errors.

Comment: Replacing the image with `example-image` the document compiles without any problems. Do you get this error with the exact code example from your question?